# Google data store inconsistent result fetch from select

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I seriously need help with GDS and PHP-GDS Library.

I am doing a fetch from outside google appengine using the fantastic php-gds library. So far the library works fine.

My problem is that my data fetch from GDS returns inconsistent results and I have no idea what the issue might be.

Please see code below:

```
    <?php
    //...
    //...
    $offset = 0;
    do{
       $query = "SELECT * FROM `KIND` order by _URI ASC limit 300 offset ".$offset;
       $tableList=[];
       $tableList = $this->obj_store->fetchAll($query);
       $offset += count($tableList);
       $allTables[] = $tableList;
       $totalRecords = $offset;
    }while(!empty($tableList));

    echo $totalRecords; // i expect total records to be equal to the number of entities in the KIND.
                        // but the results are inconsistent. In some cases, it is correct 
                        // but in most cases it is far less than the total records.
// I could have a KIND with 750 entities and only 721 will be returned in total.
// I could have a KIND with 900 entities and all entities will be returned.
// I could have a KIND with 4000 entities and only 1200 will be returned.
    ?>
```

Please help. Also when I run the exact same query in the cloud console I get the right entity count. (Hope this helps someone)

> UPDATE

I ended up using cursors. New code below:

```
<?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `KIND`";
  $tableList=[];
  $queryInit = $this->obj_store->query($query);
  do{
      $page = $this->obj_store->fetchPage(300);// fetch page.
      $tableList = am($tableList,$page); //merge with existing records.
      $this->obj_store->setCursor($this->obj_store->getCursor());//set next cursor to previous last cursor
  }while(!empty($page)); //as long as page result is not empty.
?>
```

Comment: If some/all of the entities you're querying are recently created then it's expected behaviour due to eventual consistency: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/

Comment: Thanks Dan, but there are actually no recently created entities in the KIND I am querying from.  I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a cursor instead of an offset.  See the discussion of cursors (including samples in PHP) here:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-cursor-paging-php

Comment: Thanks @JefferyRennie I was hoping I could get it done without cursors. I was going to post my final solution and then saw your answer.